# .NET 6.0 C# "new console template" - how to read CLI arguments?

Tags: c#, command-line-interface, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Now that .NET 6.0 is out, what appears to have be a radical update to the default CLI project template is the absence of the familiar boilerplate being reduced to the following:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

What is not clear (and I have been trying to find documentation thus far, to no avail) is how does one access the command-line arguments passed to the executable's entrypoint class?

Comment: Just because explicitly specifying the `Main` method isn't needed anymore (because it's added automatically in the background) it doesn't mean it's not allowed ...

Comment: Just follow the link in the comment, it spells out what to do when you need Main().

Comment: The intent of the question is to assist those who wish to embrace the new way of working with such project templates, for lack of clarity in documentation due to it being 'bleeding edge'.  Using the original template basically means "don't use the new template" which is a regressive approach.

Comment: @HansPassant The link does not document the alternate way of accessing CLI arguments with the new template. My question is not asking for how to use `Main()`.

Comment: Ridiculous move by MS team, loosing the beauty of C#, and making things not so obvious - where's the namespace, is it a plain main() or async main(), etc etc.

Comment: @joedoenot To be fair, I would question the need of an `async Main()` seeing as though most executable process entrypoints are on the main process thread. Who's going to be `await`-ing?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can access the command line arguments from anywhere in your code using the [Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment?view=net-6.0) class.

In particular, you can use [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=net-6.0):

```
string name = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1];
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}!");
```

Note that the first element in the array contains the path of the executable and the arguments passed to the program start with the second element, i.e. at index 1.

Comment: I was checking and this work too:

Console.WriteLine($"Hello, World! {args[1]}");

Comment: @Peres Yes, that's *Guru Stron*'s answer

Answer (score 77):

New project templates are using C# 9 feature called [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements).

For top-level statement file compiler will generate [`string[] args`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements#build-a-magic-net-answer-machine) parameter (actually it [generates](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCEE4AUBDATgcwM4DoAyApgHYYAuAFgJQDcQA=) the whole class containing `Main` method), so you can just use it (as previously was done with `Main(string[] args)`):

```cs
Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
Console.WriteLine(args.FirstOrDefault());
```

More info about the generation patterns can be found in [the Top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements#semantics) feature spec. Also see the [Top-level statements - programs without Main methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements#args) doc.

Comment: Doesn't compile as `args` is not defined.

Comment: @djtubig-malicex I have it compiling on my machine, at shraplab.io (one of the links in the answer) and here is [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9kbG56).

Comment: Why does this feel *pythonic*?

Comment: @IAbstract even in python you still need to explicitly `import sys` to access `sys.argv`.

Comment: Works fine for me, thanks :)

args.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x}!"));

Comment: Thanks Guru, as a note, the args parameter tech specification is found on here(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements#args)

Answer (score 5):

Little late to the game but there is a default setup already for this in .NET 6.  Use 'args' that is built in.  It's pretty much the exact old school

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

Just giving giving you 'args' as a variable that's just there for reuse.  I actually just found it on accident seeing the 'locals' pop up on VS 2022.

If I want to debug test a console app just use the 'launchSettings.json' under profiles>ConsoleApp>commandLineArgs.

So if I have in a startup:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "ConsoleApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "Brett Robel"
    }
  }
}
```

And in my .NET 6 command line app:

```
var firstName = args.First();
var lastName = args.Last();
Console.WriteLine($"Hello {firstName} and Last {lastName}");
```

I should see:

[image]

Comment: Wow, discovering how to use a new feature by "found it on accident seeing the 'locals' pop up" is not a well thought out way to deliver new features MS! MS needs to do better

Comment: on json file - how to get the "commandName" value from console ?

Answer (score 2):

In Progam.cs you can just get the parameters from the args[] array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to complicate your life, there is a [Command-line configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#command-line-configuration-provider) that can be used with Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.

Answer (score -5):

You are referring to **Top-level statements** which Microsoft introduced in C# language version 9 to mimic Python's plain syntax in an effort to rival their appeal especially to novice programmers.

Top-level statements can take input arguments like so:

```
using System;

string[] args = new string[1];

Console.WriteLine($"Hello {args[0]}");
```

If you compile the above C# code to `Program.exe` and navigate to its folder, from there you can then simply call it and pass it an input argument from the command line like so:

```
Program.exe world
```

Comment: This is really a duplicate of a prior answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70142709/125981 that has more reference links.